# Combine two command defined as String in variable and run as one

Tags: command-line, bash, join

Can I join two commands defined as String and run as one. E.g.

```
var=$(ls -alt)
var2="| grep usersfile"
'{$var & $var2;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `&` operator to combine two commands.

example:

```
mkdir folder & cd folder
```

But in case you want to give the first commands output as input to the second command, 
you can always trust the pipeline `|`

example:

```
ls -l | grep <keyword>
```

Comment: I hope this was useful ;-)